# How to add a "custom" date field to a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

Hey guys, I'm building a portfolio (which is a custom post type) and I want to store the date of the projects. I can achieve it the "regular" way with a meta box but I would like a ["datepicker"](http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/jquery-ui-datepicker) or something like it.

Any idea how?

Answer (score 1):

You want the easy way? Install the [More Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-fields/) plugin and create your custom field using that. One of the field types is a datepicker: select that when creating the custom field and you've got a datepicker.

Other plugins of interest:

- [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields)
- [Custom Content Type Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/)
- [Custom Field Template](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/)

Comment: 'More Fields' datepicker is just another metabox :(

Comment: Found out that 'Custom Field Template' plugin works better! :) But still, I would rather use a "date" meta box instead of Custom Fields. If anyone has a solution for it…

Comment: Anything in a meta box(pretty much anything anyway) is going to be getting saved as post meta, anything you use is essentially going to be meta(a custom field) under the hood.

Comment: ... unless of course you add a new column to the wp_posts table, which is not a good idea, in the long run.